# meteor make user's schema collection2 to login

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-collection2

I'd like use this schema as user and login or extend form users.I read documentation and I don't understand how extends from users. how I can make it?

`Dipendenti = new Mongo.Collection('dipendenti');
    DipendentiSchema = new SimpleSchema({
        nome: {
            type: String
        },
        cognome:{
            type: String
        },
        codiceFiscale:{
            type: String
        },
        telefono:{
            type: String
        },
        indirizzo:{
            type: String
        }
    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to extend/merge the schema listed above to the users collection. If so, you just need to attach the schema to the collection.

```
Meteor.users.attachSchema(DipendentiSchema);
```

UPDATE:

To use this new merged schema, you should be able to do something like:

```
Accounts.createUser({
  username: 'test',
  email: 'test@example.com',
  password: 'password',
  nome: 'Richard',
  cognome: 'Ortiz',
  codiceFiscale: 'EUR',
  telefono: '+39 06 49911',
  indirizzo: 'Piazzale Aldo Moro, 5, 00185 Roma, Italy'
});
```

If you want to make email address optional in your schema, you can add the following to it.

```
emails: {
    optional: true,
    type: [Object]
},
"emails.$.address": {
    optional: true,
    type: String
},
"emails.$.verified": {
    optional: true,
    type: Boolean
}
```

UPDATE 2:

Ensure that you are defining and attaching the schema wherever you are trying to make changes to the users collection. It is generally considered a best practice to do your database changes only on the server for security. You could write a method on the server using `Meteor.methods({});` and then call it on the client with `Meteor.call({});` and pass it your user data. You can read more about this approach the [Meteor documentation](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html).

Comment: if i'd like create a user as dipedenti. how make it?

Comment: I've updated my answer above to show how to use the merged schema with the users colleciton.

Comment: email can be optional?

Comment: Yes. If you set it up in your schema properly, email can be optional. See my new update on what to add to your schema in order to do this.

Comment: i used this code : 
` 'submit #dip'(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
  
  let dipendente={
   username: $('[name=nick]').val(),
   email: $('[name=email]').val(),
   password: $('[name=password]').val(),
   nome: $('[name=nome]').val,
   cognome: $('[name=cognome]').val,
   codiceFiscale: $('[name=codiceFiscale]').val,
   telefono: $('[name=codiceFiscale]').val,
   indirizzo: $('[name=telefono]').val
  }
      Accounts.createUser(dipendente);
 }
});`
the cosole.log(server) return this : 'createUser' Error: After filtering out keys not in the schema, your object is now empty

Comment: `Exception while invoking method 'createUser' Error: After filtering out keys not in the schema, your object is now empty
I20160914-18:22:58.332(2)?     at [object Object].doValidate (packages/aldeed_collection2-core/lib/collection2.js:387:1)
I20160914-18:22:58.333(2)?     at [object Object].Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function) [as insert] (packages/aldeed_collection2-core/lib/collection2.js:185:1)
I20160914-18:22:58.333(2)?     at AccountsServer.Ap.insertUserDoc (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1294:25)`

Comment: Do you get that same error if you run the `Accounts.createUser` method that I have in my answer?

Comment: `'click .fa-plus': function() {
  Accounts.createUser({
  username: 'test',
  email: 'test@example.com',
  password: 'password',
  nome: 'Richard',
  cognome: 'Ortiz',
  codiceFiscale: 'EUR',
  telefono: '+39 06 49911',
  indirizzo: 'Piazzale Aldo Moro, 5, 00185 Roma, Italy'
 });` , the console log return the same error

Comment: Where are you defining and attaching your schema? On the client, server or both? That error seems like you may have defined and attached your schema on the server, but not the client.

Comment: Yes on the server, in that case I must create the user on the server with one method?

Comment: Thanks a lot! You was very patient. Last answer it's possible return the id of user created?

Comment: It is generally considered a best practice to do your database changes only on the server for security. You could write a method on the server using `Meteor.methods({});` and then call it on the client with `Meteor.call({});` and pass it your user data. You can read more about this approach at https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html.

Comment: To get the new user id, you might look into `Accounts.onCreateUser()` at https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-onCreateUser or a simpler solution would be to query the `Meteor.users` collection, sort by the date the records were created to get most recent first and limit the results to 1. Something like this: `Meteor.users.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 }, limit: 1 }).fetch()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot again!

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help.